# JavaScript приостановка кода

Tags: javascript

Есть некоторый цикл в котором есть условия, в некоторых условиях нужно выполнить приостановку кода, именно приостановку, а не выполнение с задержкой.

Пример:

```
let arr = [100,75,50,25,0];

for (let i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
    if (arr[i]== 100) {
        setTimeout(writeline,500,arr[i]);
    } else if(arr[i]==25) {
        setTimeout(writeline,500,arr[i]);
    } else {
        writeline(arr[i]);
    }

}
function writeline (arg) {
    console.log(arg);
}
```

Вывод в консоль будет: `75   50   0  *задержка 0.5s*  100   *задержка 0.5s*   25`

А нужно что бы было `*задержка 0.5s*   100   75   50  *задержка 0.5s*   25   0`

Comment: чем отличается "приостановка кода" от "задержки" ? Расскажите поясните

Comment: В примере с "setTimeout" выполняется "задержка"  на выполнение указанной функции, а остальной код идет дальше. Под приостановкой я имел ввиду, что бы код не шел дальше, пока не выполнится "setTimeout".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [100,75,50,25,0];

async function go(arr) {
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {          
      if (arr[i]== 100) {                
          console.log(await wait(1500));
          writeline(arr[i]);
      } else if(arr[i]==25) {
          console.log(await wait(1500));          
          writeline(arr[i]);          
      } else {
          writeline(arr[i]);
      }

  }
}

function writeline (arg) {
    console.log(arg);
}

async function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(`Ждали ${ms} ms`), ms)
  });
}

go(arr);
```